# can ng-class set a timeout after a class is attached to element angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angularjs

so I have a form element

```
<form name='form' novalidate ng-class="{'shake':form.$invalid && submitted}">
   <input type='text' name='text' ng-model='text' ng-class="{'has-error':form.text.$error.required && submitted}"/>
   <button type='submit' ng-click='submit(form)'>click</button>
</form>
```

so whenever I click the button it will validate the form and add a class "shake" into form whenever the form is invalid which is in another mean the input type text doesn't take an input..

it works well, the question is.. can I remove the "shake" class after let say 5 second ?

so the flow maybe like this

form invalid -> attach "shake" class -> after 5 second -> remove "shake" class

how can I achieve this in angularjs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this on your click event..

```
$scope.submitFunction = function(expression) {  
   $timeout(function() {
       angular.element(#formId).removeClass("shake");
   }, 5000);        
};
```

Also do not forget to include dependency on your controller.

```
function YourCtrl($scope, $timeout){
}
```

Just an additional info, you can use `ng-submit` in your form element. It makes your code more readable as angularjs is trying to achieve this.

Comment: yap I tried it, it works but it take effect to the input html as well while what I want is just the form remove the "shake" class... any idea on that ?

Comment: @EkaRudiAnto I updated the answer. Use angular.element which helps you to remove the class. Just give an id to your form tag and use it

Comment: @EkaRudiAnto did the answer help you solve the problem? If not, let me know. If it did, then grade the answer somehow so we know the effect

Comment: well actually I tried it.. it works well at first but when I tried to click the button again it didn't attach the "shake" class into the form.. I don't know.. I'll try the ng-submit using custom directives now though ... will update the comment in a minute ;)

Comment: @EkaRudiAnto Thats easy, before validation just make sure that you add the shake class. Then you do the logic or validation you want. So the first line of the click fucntion is angular.element(#formId).addClass("shake")

Comment: omg why didn't I think of that sooner... great man it is work! thank you for your help man @YagizOzturk

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a timeout? Either javascript's built-in `setTimeout` or angular's [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout)

Comment: can you use it inside the ng-class directives ? can you embed it in here ? "ng-class="{'shake':form.$invalid && submitted}"

Comment: you can call it in your `submit` function